# bind id's in 'where' and 'and' operator one by one

Tags: sql

I have of query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
    WHERE source_id IN ('123','124')
        AND data_id IN ('1','2')
```

How can change it, to apply first `source_id` (123) only to first `data_id` (1) and second `source_id` (124) to only second `data_id` (2)?

Comment: Are you using MySQL?  If not, then what is your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this, depending on your database, would be to use tuple syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (source_id, data_id) IN (('123', '1'), ('124', '2'));
```

If the above does not work, then you are left with the option given by @A.khalifa.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
    WHERE source_id IN ('123') AND data_id IN ('1') or 
   source_id IN ('124') AND data_id IN ('2')
```

Hope useful